# jQuery draggable : the draggable box go over the container - bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QhVNr/) code :

## HTML

```
<div class="draggable_container">
    <div id="draggable_1" class="draggable">
        <div class="exp"><!-- --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
html
{
    height:3000px;
}

.draggable_container
{
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
    width:140px;
}

.draggable
{
    height:60px;
    width:130px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:5px solid #000000;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

Now, if you click on the box "draggable" and you move the mouse up and down, it will move till the container height.

But, if you click with the mouse to this box, and you scroll the page (with the mouse wheel...or moving the cursor to the bottom, without release the mouse) the box go over the container. And this sucks.

Is it a common bug? How can I fix this trouble?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a bug, but I solve it by adding `overflow:auto` to the `.draggable_container` css class. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/QhVNr/2/

Comment: Thank you, but It doesnt works with IE7, damn! :) Also, it's strange that it works with `overflow:auto` : it doesnt make sense!

Comment: I know, the IE has change the browser mode without notice

Comment: at the moment, I've resolved checking the top element distance (top:0 to 166). If it is <0 or >166 I just return the function! Seems a good workaround :)

Comment: Have you tried it out of jsfiddle? ni the jquery page seems work ok http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: I know! I quite resolve the problem! I'll post another topic as soon as possible ;)