# jQuery draggable and mousewheel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mousewheel

UPDATED

Found another one but not the one I wanted 
[jQuery draggable : the draggable box go over the container - bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656653/jquery-draggable-the-draggable-box-go-over-the-container-bug)

I want to scroll the box with mouse wheel,

http://jsfiddle.net/QhVNr/2/

Is that possible to move that box with mouse wheel? I cannot find any attr could use or options.

Wish someone could help me.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. Now what HTML are you working with?

Comment: Thanks David, What do you mean HTML? I am using HTML5 also HTML<5. :-) could you please show me an example? Thanks again

Comment: What HTML elements do you have on your page that you want to move in response to the scroll event?

Comment: oh right, sorry, I am working the same codes as example page, the element is draggable `$(function() {
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 });`, I want to move the draggable box itself. Do I need to use an extra jQuery like mousewheel or I can achieve from draggable UI. thanks

Comment: made a it online, http://jsfiddle.net/eCZH4/172/  just want to move the box with mousewheel